# Converting GNU asm calls to VC++

Tags: visual-c++, assembly

I have been porting a linux application to windows platform.

Here is the linux code,

```
 __asm__ __volatile__ ("lock; cmpxchgl %1, %2"
                      : "=a" (prev)
                      : "q" (new_value), "m" (*ptr), "0" (old_value)
                     : "memory");
```

I tried using _asm volatile but I get an error saying "inline assembler syntax error in 'opcode'; found 'data type'" in Visual studio 2012.

I need something windows equivalent code. 
Any info/suggestion please.

Comment: Surely your compiler has intrinsics for atomic operations? No need for writing your own assembler...

Answer (score 1):

In general, I prefer external assembly modules to inline assembly - it's more portable (yeah, portable and assembly used in the same sentence). Assemblers like [nasm](http://www.nasm.us/) and [yasm](http://yasm.tortall.net/) are available for multiple platforms, and can produce multiple object file formats.

External assembly modules aren't good for really performance-critical one-liners like your code - consider using compiler intrinsics instead of inline assembly. You might want to check out [Portable Compare And Swap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158374/portable-compare-and-swap-atomic-operations-c-c-library).

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem here is that Visual Studio uses Intel style inline assembly language, which you are not using.

Check this out:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ks26t93%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Concerning the volatile specifier and reordering, even using o2 optimization I have not yet seen VS 2010 or 2012 reordering __asm blocks.

Greetings,
Andy